# Improve the code to get the selected items from select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Below is the code which i am using to select a item from one select tag and adding it a another select tag. Now the problem is the my first select tag contains over 10000 items. And my code checks whether the each item is selected in select tag one and if selected then checks whether the same item exist in the second select tag. This is very inefficient since it takes a lot of time do so. Can any one suggest a better code by which i can directly get the multiple selected items from the select tag one and then i only have to check whether they exist in second select tag and add them.

```
if(Name.selectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                for(i=0;i<Name.options.length;i++)
                {

                    if(Name.options[i].selected)
                    {

                        exist   = false
                        for(j=0;j<addedScrips.options.length;j++)
                        {

                            if(addedScrips.options[j].value == Name.options[i].value)
                            {
                                exist   = true;
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                        if(exist == false)
                        {
                            optVal =    Name.options[i].value;
                            optText = Name.options[i].text;
                            if(optVal == "NoMatch")
                            {}
                            else
                            {
                                addedScrips.options[addedScrips.options.length] =   new Option(optText,optVal);
                              break;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //sortOptions(addedScrips)
            }
```

Comment: can you put your html code part?

Comment: HTML code contains simple 2 select tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
```

on a multi-select list, you will get an array of all the selected values.
Then use the array to filter and then add the missing values to your second list.

Hope this helped.

PS: Having a select with 10.000 values is a pain and not exactly user friendly ... i would suggest you to use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which has a nice search option for the select/multi-selects.